# jQuery validation and ajaxForm needs submit button to be clicked twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Submit button needs to be clicked twice to submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170321/submit-button-needs-to-be-clicked-twice-to-submit-form)

I have the following jquery function in my code. I have to click the 'submit' button twice to get the form submit to work. I could use ajaxSubmit function and then everything works fine but the problem with jquery is that the submit button's value itself is not passed as part of post

i have `isset($_POST['submit'])` check on all my subpages and using `ajaxSubmit`, this criteria is never set

```
        $("#bulkeditshowForm").validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                $('#bulkeditshowForm').ajaxSubmit({ 
                    // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
                    target: '#bulkeditResult', 
                    beforeSubmit: function(){

                    },
                    success: function() { 

                                 }
                       });
```

How do I use ajaxSubmit function and also submit the 'submit' button value through the form???
I need to the submit variable set when the form is submitted..ajaxForm does it, but I need to click th submit button twice...ajaxSubmit is the solution but it doesnt set the submit variable itself!!!

Please help!!!

Comment: @Sparky672, did u edit anything in the above code as part of solution?

Comment: I did not edit anything in your code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10164960/revisions

Comment: You've told us some things.  But you haven't really asked a direct question.

Comment: @Marc: I need to the submit variable set when the form is submitted..ajaxForm does it, but I need to click th submit button twice...ajaxSubmit is the solution but it doesnt set the submit variable itself!!!

Comment: Please do not repost questions.