# Submit button needs to be clicked twice to submit form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following jquery function in my code. I have to click the 'submit' button twice to get the form submit to work. I could use ajaxSubmit function and then everything works fine but the problem with jquery is that the submit button's value itself is not passed as part of post.

I have `isset($_POST['submit'])` check on all my subpages and using `ajaxSubmit`, this criteria is never set.

```
$("#bulkeditshowForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#bulkeditshowForm').ajaxForm({ 
            // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
            target: '#bulkeditResult', 
            beforeSubmit: function(){
                },
            success: function() { 
                }
        });
```

How do I use ajaxSubmit function and also submit the 'submit' button value through the form?
I need to the submit variable set when the form is submitted. ajaxForm does it, but I need to click the submit button twice. ajaxSubmit is the solution but it doesn't set the submit variable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About "ajaxSubmit" part of yor question:
Your can add any parameters to ajaxSubmit call, so your form parameters and all added parameters will be submitted:

```
    //Take submit button value
    var submitButtonValue = $("#submitButtonId").val();
    $("#bulkeditshowForm").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#bulkeditshowForm').ajaxForm({
          // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response
          target: '#bulkeditResult',
          //add submit button value to ajaxSubmit
          data: {'your_parameter_name':submitButtonValue},
          beforeSubmit: function() {
          },
          success: function() {
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not good in jquery but you can change submit button name and use that name which you check in pages in input type hidden